# Webdriverjs - By is not defined

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, webdriver-io

I am using webdriverjs, to open a website and select an element by its id. The code is,

```
var webdriverjs = require('webdriverjs'),
    client      = webdriverjs.remote({desiredCapabilities:{browserName:'phantomjs'}}).init();

client.url('www.google.com', function(err){
  client.findElement(webdriverjs.By.id('lst-ib')).sendKeys('duck duck go\n')
})
```

It throws error as,

```
webdriverjs.By is undefined
```

How to use `By` function in `webdriverjs`?

Comment: "webdriverjs" is deprecated. Use [tag:webdriver-io].

Answer (score 5):

I think you can still use webdriverjs, but their example code has a mistake

https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/WebDriverJs

the code in their example

driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("webdriver");

driver.findElement(By.name("btnG")).click();

should be

driver.findElement(webdriver.By.name("q")).sendKeys("webdriver");

driver.findElement(webdriver.By.name("btnG")).click();

I am not sure why it is incorrect on the website.

Answer (score 3):

All the above are old and you can now use `selenium-webdriver` instead. In my case I'd simply forgotten to include `By` and my IDE wasn't helpful.

`ReferenceError: By is not defined`

I just needed:

`const {By} = require('selenium-webdriver');`

A complete example as of 02022020, including using chromedriver to set path!

```
const webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
const chrome = require('selenium-webdriver/chrome');
const chromedriver = require('chromedriver');
const { By, Key } = webdriver; // Using object destructuring for convenience - or webdriver.By

chrome.setDefaultService(new chrome.ServiceBuilder(chromedriver.path).build());

const driver = new webdriver.Builder()
    .withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.chrome())
    .build();

driver.get('https://www.google.com');

driver.findElements(By.xpath('//input[@type="text"]'))
    // ES6 desturcturing usage. Could be: (inputs), and then inputs[0].sendKeys...
    .then(([searchInput]) => {
        // inputs[0].sendKeys(...words);
        searchInput.sendKeys('stack overflow bumper stickers')
            .then(() => {
                searchInput.sendKeys(Key.ENTER);
            });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

From the webdriverjs npm page...

> DEPRECATED
>   Project is now called WebdriverIO and has moved to webdriverio/webdriverio on GitHub. Please use $ npm install webdriverio because this NPM project is not maintained anymore!

So `require('webdriverio');` is probably your best bet. Instead of 
`client.findElement(webdriverjs.By.id('lst-ib')).sendKeys('duck duck go\n')`
simply
`client.setValue('#lst-ib','duck duck go', function(err, res){
    //some callback here
});`

Comment: Saravana have you been able to implement this with webdriver.io?

Answer (score -1):

```
    var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'),
        By = webdriver.By,
        until = webdriver.until;
```

please try this?